# Laravel generating students ID

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello am creating a school management system i want to generate student ID like this 2022-0001,2022-0002 when you select 2023 it will reset to 2023-0001 and so on please help

Comment: Please show us what you have attempted so far and where you are having problems. StackOverflow is not a code writing service, the community provides assistance with debugging and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar few years ago. I would still use a "standard" ID in DB, store the year in separate field and generate my custom in another field.

```
// Get the current number of student for the year and add 1
$number = Student::where('year', date('Y'))->count() + 1;
// Make your custom ID
$myCustomId = date('Y') . '-' . sprintf('%04s', $number);
```

I don't think there is a specific "Laravel way" for doing that. I would go that way.

Of course, if you want to be able to create customId with year which isn't the current year, use custom logic instead of date('Y').